# Pass CSS property dynamically  from panelgrid 

Tags: css, jsf

I have a hidden property which is fetched from ebean. how do i pass that color code property to css function?

```
    <h:panelGrid id="testpanel"
       columns="#{message.no_of_columns}" rows="#{message.no_of_rows}" 
      styleClass="dynamicGrid">
     <c:forEach items="#{bLDashBoardAction.listBondLoc}" var="item">
      <h:panelGroup>                                                 <h:outputText value="#{item.rackTagCode}" />
   <h:hiddenInput value="#{item.colorEBean.colorCode};" />
                                            </h:panelGroup>
</c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

this is my css property,background need to be assigned from panelgrid colorcode

```
.dynamicGrid td
{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border: 4px solid gray;
    background:

}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you storing CSS color codes in a DB instead of in a CSS file? This makes it all unnecessarily overcomplicated.

Comment: hi BalusC ,that is one of requirement where color of each box can be configured by user.i'm still not able to get it done.is there any alternative way to do it? i tried daniel's way but couldnt get the result.

Comment: Why don't you just store CSS class names in the DB?

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the db structure,but i could suggest this to them

Comment: i was asked to not to use css from database,advised to bind the color code in jsf and rest properties refer to one css class.i have to stick back with this method,now i only able to fill the text background instead of box background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're restricted by strange design, your best bet is really to apply the style directly on the cell's content instead.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.rackTagCode}" style="display:block;color:#{item.colorEBean.colorCode};" />
```

The `display:block` will make it to span the entire cell.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can pass from JSF to css , you can create several classes with predefined background color , like `.dynamicGridRed` and `.dynamicGridYellow`

and call them conditionally `styleClass="#{item.colorEBean.colorCode}"`
 wher colorCode can return `dynamicGridRed` or `dynamicGridYellow`

or something like

```
styleClass="#{item.colorEBean.useRedCode?'dynamicGridRed':'dynamicGridYellow'}"
```

another option would be use inline css like:

```
style="width: 50px;height: 50px;border: 4px solid gray;background:#{item.colorEBean.colorCode}"
```

INMO , you better not try to manipulate the content of css, just make a bunch of predefined css classes...

but I'm not a css pro , so i might be wrong

Comment: thanks for the reply.do i need to overwrite the css property class?sorry bit confused

Comment: thanks ya. inline doesn't work .i have created bunch of predefined css classes.how do i refer to that property ?should i use a JavaScript function?

Comment: no js needed , one way would be `styleClass="#{item.colorEBean.className}"` where `className` will hold the name of your class